# SQL Calculate Percentage of one Column to Another

Tags: sccm

I want to find out what percent a number is of another number. I'm new to SQL and I'm confused on how to go about this. I've been following videos and tutorials with no luck. I want this to work like below.

[image]

Comment: Please show the code in your question, not just as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to calculate the percentage of integers.  You need to cast the integers to a Datatype that supports Decimals.  Try this:

```
select cast(pfe.TotalManagedSystem as Float) / cast(pfe.AllSystems as Float) as Percentage;
```

Or:

```
select cast(pfe.TotalManagedSystem as decimal) / cast(pfe.AllSystems as decimal) as Percentage;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is now a decimal number and you've actually taught me something more straight forward than some of the tutorials I've been watching.